# what is the difference between directory-based format project and file-based format project in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, project

I went through the IntelliJ IDEA documantation here http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/project.html and it describes the structure of a directory-based format project and a file-based format project, why should i prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The file-based format was the only one available in older versions of IntelliJ IDEA. The directory-based format was introduced later, and its main advantage is that it's easier to store project files in the version control system, because the project data is split over multiple files, and merge conflicts are less likely.

The downside is relatively minor: you can't open a directory-based project by double-clicking it in a file manager of your operating system.

Comment: The directory based format also helps to commit only shared settings, leaving out user specific settings (e.g. whether to show line numbers in editor).  From [Intellij Support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206167769/comments/206289015)

Comment: @Neeraj That's not exactly true. With the file-based format, user-specific settings are also stored in a separate file (.iws), which should also never be committed.